# How flexible is order of build phases for Xcode targets?

Tags: xcode, xcode6.1

Is it possible to configure the Build Phases of a target in Xcode 6.1 such that a Copy Files phase can occur before the Compile Sources phase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

For existing phases such as "Copy" and "Compile" in your example:

- View the Build Phases by selecting the Build Phases tab in the desired project's target
- Then reorder phases (or elements of each phase) by dragging them using your mouse

Note: The "Target Dependencies" phase may not be reordered (at the time of this writing).

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Everytime I try to move one of the phases it snaps back immediately, see https://www.dropbox.com/s/aj9eil6cxix0zsu/xcode_cordova_prepare.mov?dl=0

Comment: I only seem to be able to drag items from the middle to the bottom. Therefore I have to shuffle them all down to the bottom until the thing I'm trying to insert higher is in the correct place.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell there is no way to reorder items using the GUI in Xcode. You can do it by editing the `project.pbxproj` file though.

If you open that file up in some text editor (not Xcode) and do a search for something like

> Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget

You'll find a section like this

```
/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */
    9BDEC0D019881B9400AE439B /* MyProject */ = {
        isa = PBXNativeTarget;
        buildConfigurationList = 9BDEC0F019881B9400AE439B /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "MyProject" */;
        buildPhases = (
            6111D3671B56D2BB00DD7431 /* Show TODOs and FIXMEs as Warnings */,
            BAEE6F558B6BDB326F5B8D1F /* Check Pods Manifest.lock */,
            9BDEC0CD19881B9400AE439B /* Sources */,
            9BDEC0CE19881B9400AE439B /* Frameworks */,
            4C47C03A1ABD4DFE00D317B5 /* Copy baked database to bundle sqlite */,
            9BDEC0CF19881B9400AE439B /* Resources */,
            CDF5E3A80B5FDFCEA41B67FD /* Embed Pods Frameworks */,
            CF995761C5EAA8D1AAEBA463 /* Copy Pods Resources */,
        );
        buildRules = (
        );
        dependencies = (
            9B832FED19B76A45006D3347 /* PBXTargetDependency */,
        );
        name = MyProject;
        productName = MyProject;
        productReference = 9BDEC0D119881B9400AE439B /* MyProject.app */;
        productType = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    };
```

**You can change the order of operations in the `buildPhases` list.**

*See how the first thing in my list is `6111D3671B56D2BB00DD7431 /* Show TODOs and FIXMEs as Warnings */,`? That is a custom build phase script I added using the GUI and then moved that line up to be the first using Atom. Reopened the GUI and it was the second build phase after "Target Dependencies" (as was mentioned in the other answer).*

Comment: fwiw, as of XCode 9.2, the "Target Dependencies" phase does not appear in this list, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode you can reorder the Build Phases in the GUI (XCode 6.4 and 7.1 beta), but sometimes the UI is somehow blocked. Try the following steps in order to unblock the UI:

1. click on Build Rules,
2. click on Build Phases,
3. move the desired phase one step at a time.

Comment: You are repeating @justin's answer, aren't you?

Comment: I was referring to Spencevail's statement, that the items can not be reordered. There has been for a long time (and still is) a bug in Xcode, that would prevent you from moving the rows. But if you switch tabs back and forth, the bug can be circumvented.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem with XCode 7.1.1 (maybe exists from XCode 7). I could not drag recently added Run Scripts to anywhere, found I could drag *existing* items to the bottom though.  So, if my items were

```
A
B
C
D (New runscript)
```

and I wanted to put D below A, first drag B to the bottom

```
A
C
D
B
```

and then drag C to the bottom

```
A
D
B
C
```

Hope that helps someone.